# How do I get Rails to recognize environment variables defined in config/environment_variables.yml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, ruby-on-rails-5, environment

With Rails 5, if I create a file, config/environment_variables.yml, that contains

```
development:
  MY_VAR: abcdef
```

What do I need to do to get the Rails environment to recognized that environment variable?  Right now, when I go to my console (by typing "rails console") on my local machine, it isn't turning up anything ...

```
2.4.0 :001 > ENV['MY_VAR']
 => nil
```

Comment: Which gem are you using to get environment variables from environment_variables.yml? Rails doesn't built-in a mechanism to extract environment variables from this file.

Comment: So this is the step I'm missing.  What's the gem that allows that to happen?

Comment: If any of the answers below solved your problem, please mark it as answered. If none of the answers solved your problem, please add more detail or comment so we can continue to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wish to use a gem, you can place this in your `config/application.rb`

```
# Load application ENV vars and merge with existing ENV vars. Loaded here so you can use the values in initializers.
ENV.update YAML.load_file('config/application.yml')[Rails.env] rescue {}
```

Then your `config/application.yml` file should look like:

```
development:
  API_KEY: 12345

staging:
  API_KEY: 67890
```

Be sure to restart your server, then you can access the variables as you desire with `ENV['API_KEY']`.